# Spring ControllerAdvice ExceptionHandler does not work

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to intercept tomcat default 404 page using ExceptionHandler.
All I want to do is showing the index page in case of 404.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AdvisorController {

@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public String handle404(Exception ex) {
    return "index";
}
}
```

But unfortunately I can see only tomcat default 404 page.

My web initializer looks like this:

```
public class CRManWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    //ctx.register(CRManMVCConfig.class);
    ctx.register(CRManMVCConfig.class, CRManJPAConfig.class, CRManSecurityConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(ctx);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

    Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping("/");
}
}
```

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

After removing everything is working fine. Maybe it will help somebody